# Adding an object (pin, emoji, shape) as an annotation to an Image that is not a Map

Tags: swift

I'm developing an app that users can take note on images they already have by adding an annotation to anywhere on the image, the annotation will be customizable and interactable.

It works like Facebook story picture feature that you can drag an emoji or anything else to the image, and whenever you tap on that annotation, it will lead you to another view to add more details.

I'm also having trouble to find a way to save it, because those annotations should be placed as the same spot whenever I load the image after saving it.

I've been searching for a while and haven't found any solution yet.

Could you please tell me the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.